# nginx: serve private static files

Tags: nginx

I have nodejs app behind nginx as reverse proxy.
App has both public static files and private static files (available just after login).

Nginx directly serves public static files, but private files requests are forwarded to node.
Node checks authorization cookie (not only if it exists but also if session token is correct).

I would like to serve private static files directly from Nginx too. I can check if auth. cookie exist, but not if it's valid.

Is there some pattern how to do that?

Thank you!

Comment: You can extend nginx with lua scripts, so your validity check might be doable in nginx (depends on what exactly it involves)

Comment: Thanks, I was more wondering if there is a way for nginx to ask (per each request) to App if it's authorized, then bases on answer serve it or not.

Comment: This sounds like a strange half-measure. Node should be relatively efficient at serving static files by itself. If you want to move the serving to nginx for efficiency, move the check too.

Comment: How I can move this check? I can check cookie presence but not if it has valid token. Can I share somehow with nginx what are the valid tokens at given moment?

Comment: In your node app, how do you determine that token is valid or not?

Comment: I store them in nodejs local cache synchronized into file (in case app restart)

Comment: Ah, so nginx can read this file. Although this opens a few other questions (how often to re-read the file, etc.). I'd look into using self-contained tokens (JWT). No need to store them anywhere, they have expiration built-in (the downside is that you can't revoke such token, only wait for it to expire)

Comment: how I can implement this reading? I was also looking at njs module.